# How can i create new form in django admin changelist page

Tags: python, django

I have the django changelist page overridden.

I have changed the template `change_list_results` to lokk like i want.

However i want to have small form in header like `export pdf` but when i add `form` tag to the html then Django automatically strips it because results are already inside form tag.

How can solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Results are inside the 'changelist-form' form, and by rule, you cannot add a form inside another. What you can do is to add the form outside of the 'changelist-form'.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html#L86