# Django admin remove form tag

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a form to admin panel in change_list.html with two inputs of type file and button to each line. But there is no form tag on the page.

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'upload_excel')
    
    def upload_excel(self, instance):
        href = reverse('admin:upload_excel_view', kwargs=dict(pk=instance.pk))
            return format_html(f'''<form action="{href}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="GET">
                <div>
                    <input type="file" value="Upload">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
                </div>
        </form>''')
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221036/8439435.

I think a cleaner way would be to implement an admin action with an intermediate page like described in this [documentation section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages).